# Как узнать из главного потока, что побочный поток завершился ошибкой?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть главный поток(1) и из него вызывается побочный поток(2)

Выглядит примерно так:

```
   Thread second_thread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                throws new Exception();
            }
        });
second_thread.start();
second_thread.join();
```

Как узнать из главного потока, что побочный поток завершился ошибкой?

Comment: Вы путаете поток и задачу. Вам нужно передавать в поток задачу (см. ExecutionService) и получать ее результат.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Классы Callable и Future как раз созданы чтобы решить эту проблему. Вопрос разрешен.

Answer (score 4):

Использовать `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
    }
};

Thread second_thread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        throws new Exception();
    }
});
second_thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
second_thread.start();
second_thread.join();
```

Диаграмма жизни потока при возникшем исключении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6546193/1985167)

**UPD**

Если исключение нужно получить в "родительском" потоке, то нужно использовать `Callable` и `ExecutionContext`:

```
Callable<Void> task = new Callable<Void> {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        throws new Exception();
    }
});

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Void> futureResult = executor.submit(task);

try {
    futureResult.get();
}
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // анализируете причину с помощью getCause()/initCause()
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, вариант не подходит. Мне требуется в главном потоке получить эксепшн, а не вывести в консоль. Бессмысленная манипуляция совершенно, опять приходим к методу, из которого не получается грамотно выдернуть исключение

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov обновил ответ.